# Mobile registration system. How to handle E164 and national mobile number login?

Tags: php, database-design, authentication

I'm implementing a mobile registration system in PHP where by the user can register with their mobile number. They can also log in with that number and receive SMS notices/verification etc.

Let me explain the system before moving onto the problem as its easier to explain that way.

My current system works like this:

1. User signs up with `07733333333`
2. Phone number is converted to E164 format and stored as `+44773333333`
3. SMS validation is sent

This works great and ensures the user can't sign up twice with the same number. It's also the format our SMS service provider requires.

The way I convert to E164 is using Google's LibPhoneNumber library. It requires a country code to convert the number so I take that from the IP address. The user is able to change the country code if our guess is wrong. On the page after registration they will see a page that says "We've sent an SMS to this number: +44773333333". The user can change this number/country code at this point.

The problem arises when logging in.

If a user logs in with `+44773333333` it's easy to grab this from the database. It's already stored in this format.

But, if they log in with `0773333333` I need to make a guess at what region that mobile number is to convert it to E164 format to run the query. There is no way I can query this number in the database because it doesn't exist in that form. I can guess that it's `+44` from the IP address but this is unreliable. What if the user is on holiday? Or using a VPN? That guess can't be made.

What is the best way to handle this?

My only thought is to have two fields in the database. One is `national_mobile_number` and the other is `e164_mobile_number`. That way I can query either fields to see if the numbers match. I don't know what impact this would have on performance with many users (500,000+).

Comment: How about requiring from the user to always specify the country code?

Comment: @BartoszZasada that's a good question. This was decided against as the demographics that will use the application will unlikely know how to use mobile numbers with a country code. Facebook for example don't require this either when registering. I fear this will stop a percentage of users from registering if they end up confused.